# How do language implementations represent an empty list?

Tags: list, data-structures

Each node in a singly linked list is some data and a pointer to the next item (or a null pointer if it's the tail of the list).

Every language that I know of with a native list type has support for an 'empty' list, usually with some literal syntax for it.

How would this be represented in the machine's memory?

I can think of a few ways:

- in languages with runtime type information (i.e. a type / value pair), it could be a 'list' type with a null value item
- a null pointer for the data item in the list node (But this only works when it's a "pointer" type, not a value embedded directly in the node data structure)
- a special symbolic value

Does this vary widely between languages, or is there a standard way to do it?

Comment: I did find this on the Wikipedia article for Lisp (referring to Common Lisp): "The empty list () is also represented as the special atom nil. This is the only entity in Lisp which is both an atom and a list."

Comment: In java its a special static final instance of an List (or Collctions) object.

Comment: a list is an abstraction of an array, and when you get down to assembly level stuff, you still generally store the starting memory address, and an integer that represents how many data items are in the array. sometimes the length is ommited, and you store a sentinal value (strings is c do this). anyway, i think everything is just a higher level abstraction of these two basic approaches.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation.

I'd imagine a pretty standard single linked-list implementation looks like this:

```
object List
  Node head

object Node
  Type data
  Node next
```

For an empty list, `List.head` will just be a null pointer.

Alternatively an empty list could be a null pointer of type `List` (though in some languages the difference between these two is non-trivial).

You could also get rid of `List` altogether and just define a list as a `Node`, then an empty list could be either:

- A null pointer of type `Node` (again not appropriate for certain languages)
- A `Node` with both `data` and `next` being null (may not be distinguishable from a list with one null element, if this is possible)

Some languages may not have the concept of a null pointer, but you should be able to exchange this for a special object.